# Bind GridView With Foreign Key Value

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework-5

Cities

```
CityID
Name
CountryID(FK)
```

Countries

```
CountryID
CountryName
```

I want to show All Cities in gridview show CountryName instead of CountryID With EntityDatasource

What is the best solution ?

Answer (score -1):

Can you inner join Countries Table and Cities table.
select t1.Name, t1.CountryId , t2.CountryId, t2.CountryName Cities t1 inner join Countries t2 on t1.CountryID=t2.CountryID

You Can Displat Cuntryname instead CountryID